# Selecting rows based on row level uniqueness (combination of columns)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I hope somebody can help me solve the following problem.

I need to select unique rows based on a combination of 2 or 3 columns. Its basically a 3 level hierachy table that I build up referening the PK as the parentId in the hierachy.

To set everything up please run the following script:

```
-- ===================
-- Source table & data
-- ===================
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ExternalSource]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExternalSource](
    [locname1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [locname2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [locname3] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END

INSERT [dbo].[ExternalSource] ([locname1], [locname2], [locname3]) VALUES (N'Location1', N'Floor1', N'Room123')
INSERT [dbo].[ExternalSource] ([locname1], [locname2], [locname3]) VALUES (N'Location2', N'Floor2', N'Room234')
INSERT [dbo].[ExternalSource] ([locname1], [locname2], [locname3]) VALUES (N'Location3', N'Floor2', N'Room111')

-- ===================
-- Destination table
-- ===================

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [LocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [LocationCode] [nvarchar](20),
    [LocationName] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [CanAssign] [bit] NOT NULL)

-- Level 1 records in the hierachy
insert into Location 
(
    CompanyID, 
    ParentID, 
    LocationName,  
    CanAssign
)
select distinct 1, NULL, ES.locname1, 1
from dbo.ExternalSource ES
where ES.locname1 not in (select LocationName from Location) and ES.locname1 is not null

-- Level 2 records in the hierachy
insert into Location 
(
    CompanyID, 
    ParentID, 
    LocationName,  
    CanAssign
)
select 1, max(Loc.LocationID), ES.locname2, 1
from ExternalSource ES
left join Location Loc on ES.locname1 = Loc.LocationName
where ES.locname2 not in (select LocationName from Location) and ES.locname2 is not null and ES.locname1 is not null
group by ES.locname2
order by ES.locname2

select * from ExternalSource
select * from Location
```

The first insert into Location is not a problem at all, all I want at the first insert is unique Location names.

Now at my second insert I need to be able to tell whether ExternalSource.locname2 & Location.LocationName are unique in a "combined" fashion, if that makes sense...

If they are unique, then I need to have the location name at level 2 selected.

Here is an example:

Below is what you get when you do a select * from ExternalSource

**locname1 locname2 locname3**

Location1 Floor1 Room123

Location2 Floor2 Room234

Location3 Floor2 Room111

Given the above, there is only one Floor1 on locname2 so no issues there but as you can see there are two Floor2 on the locname2 column. I need a way to check if the value on locname2 + locname1 are unique when "combined". If they are I should select them both.

This is the expected output of the select during the second insert:

1 1 Floor1 1

1 2 Floor2 1

1 3 Floor2 1

But lets say the output of ExternalSource where to look like this:

**locname1 locname2 locname3**

Location1 Floor1 Room123

Location2 Floor2 Room234

**Location2** Floor2 Room111

Note the bold Location2 above, because there are two rows with the same value on locname2 + locname1 it doesn't make it unique anymore and then the desired output whould have looked like this:

1 1 Floor1 1

1 3 Floor2 1

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group by two columns in ExternalSource...?

```
 select MAX(LocationID),  Locname1, Locname2, 1 from ExternalSource
 group by Locname1, Locname2
```